# Can't restore windows after windows 10 system recovery didn't finish

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, boot, system-restore, system-recovery

wanted to erase windows 10 and reset to factory conditions (windows 8) but the windows 10 system recovery didn't finish the process and hung up, so I had to shut it down. Now it won't follow through with the rest of restore at the menu options at boot. I do not have a flash drive or cd/dvd for burning a windows iso on. I am wondering if this can be resolved without a boot disc by figuring out what's causing the issue and fixing it and if anybody can help me deduce the problem.

Now I boot up and it goes into a menu which I'm assuming is part of the windows recovery, and it presents options on what to do next. When I go to Reset this PC, it says "there was a problem resetting your PC. No changes were made." When I choose "Startup Repair" it says "couldn't repair your PC." When I choose "go back to previous build" it says "we couldn't find previous build to take you back to." When I choose System Restore, it says no restore points were found. So i pretty much can't do anything.

Comment: What errors/messages/behavior are you getting when trying to start?

Comment: i boot up and it goes into a menu which I'm assuming is part of the windows recovery, and it presents options on what to do next. When I go to Reset this PC, it says "there was a problem resetting your PC. No changes were made." When I choose "Startup Repair" it says "couldn't repair your PC." When I choose "go back to previous build" it says "we couldn't find previous build to take you back to." When I choose System Restore, it says no restore points were found. So i pretty much can't do anything.

Comment: Please edit this information into your question.

Comment: ok i have included it into the original question.